# How productive was the participle in -menus in Latin?

Tags: greek, derivation, morphology, participle, origin

Greek has the medium participle ending in *-menos*.
It has a couple of occurrences in Latin, too, of which I only seem to remember *alere > alumnus* now.
How many words are there in Latin that contain this element?
What is their origin?
Are they borrowed from Greek, or was the participle or derivative suffix *-m(e)nus* ever productive in Latin?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=menus&lang=la)?

Comment: @Rafael No, I had not seen that. I suspected that there might be sound changes making suitable words hard to find. The common property is M and N which may or may not have a vowel in between.

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5149/latin-passive-endings-why-is-mini-sticking-out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Weiss cites, besides *alumnus*, *femina* (from a root meaning 'give suck'), *calumnia* (derived from *kalwo-mno-, from the root of *calvor* 'deceive'), and possibly also *columna* and the divine name *Vortumnus* (if related to *verto* 'turn', though it may rather be Etruscan). These are not Greek loans but native formations; I don't know when precisely they were formed, but the suffix doesn't seem to have been productive in Latin as we know it.

Comment: If these are all inherited from PIE instead of derived from the roots within Latin, I take it that the suffix was never productive in Latin.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, I meant that they're native rather than loanwords; I don't know when those particular forms were produced. Editing for clarity. Pretty clearly the suffix isn't productive in any stage of Latin as we know it.

Comment: What about _autumnus_?

Comment: @Rafael, *autumnus* has no accepted etymology; some think it's an Etruscan loan.

Answer (score 6):

The ending **-menos* was not productive in that form in Latin.

There are conjectures that it is the source of certain word endings.

#### Possible occurrence in *-ndus* words

[Jeremy Brightbill's review in the Bryn Mawr Classical Review](https://bmcr.brynmawr.edu/2012/2012.10.56/) of *The Latin Deverbative Nouns and Adjectives,* by Lucie Pultrová​ (2011) says that Pultrová​, apparently along with some others, proposes that the suffix *-ndo-* found in gerundives and adjectives such as *oriundus* comes from **menos* ("via the sequence * -mno- > * -nno- > * -ndo-, due to assimilation of nasals and then dissimilation").

However, there are a number of alternative hypotheses about the origin of this ending.

#### Possible occurrence in *-mens* words

It seems that some people have proposed that *-menos* developed in a few Latin words to *-mens* rather than *-mnus,* but there is no consensus in favor of this etymology either. At least one current Wiktionary entry gives an etymology based on this idea: the adjective *[clēmens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clemens),* according to Wiktionary, comes "from *clīnō* + participial suffix *-menos*".

De Vaan (2008) says an etymology from **klejomenos* was given in Walde-Hoffmann (1930-1954), and earlier by Breal and Osthoff (the "nt" in non-nominative forms would have to be analogical). However, he says "the contraction in initial syllable of **ejo* > *ē* is doubtful, and the disappearance of *o*-stem inflection completely unexpected." De Vaan thinks that a derivation from *mēns* 'mind', as given by Ernout-Meillet (1979), is "attractive". De Vaan also provides an alternative proposal for the exact form of the first part of the word to try to make the *ē* a bit more explainable, **kloi-wo-ment-*.

"Latin Etymologies" by Edwin W. Fay (1903), seems to say that Niedermann proposed deriving *vehemens* from **vehemenos,* and mentions that Osthoff connected *clēmens* to Sanskrit "*çrayamānas* 'leaning' " (Note: this seems to correspond to the [IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration) spelling śrayamāṇaḥ/śrayamāṇas.) However, Fay says that *clēmens* and *vehemens~vēmens* are basically the only evidence for *-mens* as reflex in Latin of *-menos,* and therefore Fay rejects that etymology and instead proposes that both words are originally compounds from *mens* "mind". Fay also rejects the identification of the first part of *clēmens* with *clīnō* (he finds the semantic relationship underwhelming), proposing that it instead comes from a form **tlē-* that he associates with Greek *talai-phrōn* and *tlē-thymos*; he suggests the development of the *tl* to *cl* instead of *l* is due to influence from forms prefixed with *in-,* specifically *inclēmenter.*

Osthoff's proposed etymology for *clēmens* also seems to have been mentioned by Brugmann (1891) alongside discussion of *-mnus* and *-mini.*

To clarify, the point of this post is not to endorse this etymology (nor deny it: I don't have the authority to do either!); I simply wanted to bring it up so that readers would be aware of the historical fact that in the past, some scholars suggested that *-mens* in these two words was derived from **-menus.*

#### Works Cited

"[Latin Etymologies](https://books.google.com/books?id=X9A4AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=Osthoff%20clemens%20Sanskrit&source=bl&ots=fTh23Fd3fI&sig=BdH0ltDm1fE7XifIZ31g5fuDXB8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM3ZiekvPWAhWm14MKHcNQDf4Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Osthoff%20clemens%20Sanskrit&f=false)",  Edwin W. Fay. *The American Journal of Philology* Vol. 24, No. 1 (1903), pp. 62-74

"[Comparative Grammar of the Indo-Germanic Languages](https://books.google.com/books?id=yO1YAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=Osthoff%20clemens%20Sanskrit&source=bl&ots=7wrp6x3FOl&sig=Y8EwaHhgCLJmeLyGynAljmAE9uA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm6fqMj_PWAhVH5IMKHYQ4AOcQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=Osthoff%20clemens%20Sanskrit&f=false)" Volume 2, Karl Brugmann. 1891.

*Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic Languages,* Michiel de Vaan. 2008.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this theory up! I have hard time believing it, especially since it seems that *-mens* comes from *_-ments_ just like the participles, judging by inflection. But I agree that sharing this point of view is valuable. (+1)